# Problem in some views in items row of recyclerview "not showing like design preview"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I trying to practice some android lessons that contains recyclerview topic, currently I succeed to implement all api and response but there's one problem with my `item_article_preview.xml`.

The title and description of news doesn't shows in emulator like it's in design preview

[image: design preview]

After running the app

[image]

here's my xml row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivArticleImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="TITLE" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:textColor="@color/black"

                android:text="DESCRIPTION" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSource"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="SOURCE"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPublishedAt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="PUBLISHED AT"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSource" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I tried other row design but it didn't show the title and descreption at all

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArticleImage"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSource"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="SOURCE"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivArticleImage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/ivArticleImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:text="DESCRIPTION"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivArticleImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPublishedAt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="PUBLISHED AT"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSource" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**RecyclerView XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvBreakingNews"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/paginationProgressBar"
        style="?attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**my adapter class**

```
private const val TAG = "NewsAdapter"
class NewsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ArticleViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArticleViewHolder {

        val binding = ItemRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
        return ArticleViewHolder(binding)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val article = differ.currentList[position]
//        holder.bind(article)

        holder.binding.apply {
            Glide.with(this.root).load(article.urlToImage).into(ivArticleImage)
            tvSource.text = article.source.name
            tvTitle.text = article.title
            tvDescription.text = article.description
            tvPublishedAt.text = article.publishedAt

           this@NewsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener {
               onItemClickListener?.let {
                        it(article)
                    }
           }
        }


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }

    inner class ArticleViewHolder( val binding: ItemRowBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    private var onItemClickListener: ((Article) -> Unit)? = null


    private fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (Article) -> Unit) {
        onItemClickListener = listener
    }

    private val diffCallBack = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>() {

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }

    val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, diffCallBack)
}
```

Comment: Remember that match_parent inherits it's value, so maybe in your recycler view you have wrap_content, post your rv xml

Comment: please add your adapter class

Answer (score 1):

[image]

ACTIVITY:

```
    val list : MutableList<Item> = mutableListOf()
    list.add(Item("TITLE", "DESCRITION", "ESPN", "2022-08-02T14:32:47Z"))

    val rv = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvBreakingNews)
    rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
    rv.adapter = RvAdapter(list)
```

ADAPTER

```
class RvAdapter(private var list : List<Item>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RvAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)

    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.title.setText(list[position].getTitle())
    holder.desc.setText(list[position].getDescription())
    holder.source.setText(list[position].getSource())
    holder.published.setText(list[position].getPublished())
}

// return the number of the items in the list
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}

// Holds the views for adding it to image and text
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val title : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle)
    val desc : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription)
    val source : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSource)
    val published : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPublishedAt)
    val imageView : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivArticleImage)
}

}
```

ACTIVITY XML (SAME AS YOURS):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/paginationProgressBar"
    style="?attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ITEM XML(SAME AS YOURS):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="8dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArticleImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="TITLE" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:textColor="@color/black"

            android:text="DESCRIPTION" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSource"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="SOURCE"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPublishedAt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="PUBLISHED AT"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSource" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: unfortunately the same problem

Comment: @indianaEvans the issue must be in the .java or .kt . I tried all your xml config and it works perfect

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem causes this spilled of screen, here in this line

`val binding = ItemRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))`

you just inflated the inflater of a parent but there are two parameters is missing,

the `viewGroup` which it "parent and `attachToRoot = false`

edit your `onCreateViewHolder` like this

```
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArticleViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ItemRowBinding.inflate(inflater,parent,false)
        return ArticleViewHolder(binding)

    }
```

Comment: yea this was a problem, thank you